# Bypassing CORS issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We are facing an issue where using Chrome request via XMLHTTPRequest is getting failed with below error:

> Failed to load `<server url>`: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   is present on the requested resource. Origin '`<client domain>`' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

This error is Chrome specific since we are not getting this issue in IE. Is there anyway to bypass this error in JavaScript.

Comment: There's a Chrome extension "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: " that might help.

Comment: Please post relevant codes snippets in your question.

Comment: @stever This will make the request as OPTIONS, server only supports POST

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have already checked this. However it does not state how to skip this in javascript code.

Comment: Right, because that's not possible in JavaScript code.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, for development purposes only, you can start the Chrome Browser in relaxed mode using the `disable-web-security` flag:

Here's how to do it on windows (Credit to https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/)

- Right click on desktop, add new shortcut
- Add the target as "[PATH_TO_CHROME]\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
- Click OK.

The directory in 'user-data-dir' must have read/write permissions for Chrome.

You will get a warning banner in Chrome notifying about reduces security, because that is actually what you have here. USE ONLY FOR TESTING.

Note: This answer builds on the link-only answer by Franco Fontana which was deleted because of link-only but the link actually helped me.

Comment: It works (now Nov 2023 with Chrome version 118) and it is really really useful if you want to test stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

No, fortunately there is not.

The same-origin policy is an security concept implemented by browsers to prevent Javascript code from making requests against a different origin/domain than the one from which it was served. So enabling developers to bypass this from Javascript would be a bad thing.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell a browser to let a web application running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected resources from a server at a different origin. A web application makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, and port) than its own origin.

Source: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

If you're **in control of the API**:
Add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header containing the domain your requests are originating from.

If you're **not in control of the API**:
Ask the developer of the API to have your domain added to an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

**EDIT:**
Adding the correct header will not 'make the request an `OPTIONS` request while the server only accepts `POST`'.
The `OPTIONS` request is a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) to check *to see if the CORS call can actually be made*. If the preflight request has the correct header, the `POST` request will follow as you can see in the image below:

[image: OPTIONS before POST]

You can find all of the basic CORS information in the article [Understanding CORS](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b)

Comment: Adding Access-Control parameter will make the request as HTTP OPTIONS and server only supports POST.

Comment: Nope, it will not. The `OPTIONS` request is a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) to check to see if the CORS call can actually be made. If the preflight request has the correct header, the `POST` request will follow.

Answer (score 1):

Although its limited, can try to use CORS anywhere https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere or the chrome extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) that allows you to bypass CORS (make sure you turn this off when not testing as it will cause issues with requests from other websites)